# Elixir ExUnit: Run function before the complete test suite?

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

There is the `setup` callback that is invoked before each test and the `setup_all` callback that is invoked only once per module, before any test runs.

I have the situation where I need to prepare something before the whole test suite runs. Only once. I am working with a non-standard DB and setting up the schema with all indexes takes a little. So I would like to speed up tests by not doing that more often than needed.

Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put your initialization code in `test/test_helper.exs`. Any code in that file will be executed before the tests are run and only once. As @mudasobwa pointed out, it doesn't matter if the code is before or after `ExUnit.start()`, it'll be run before the tests.

```
# your code here 

ExUnit.start()

# or here
```

Comment: Is  _“before `ExUnit.start()`”_ significant here? `test/test_helper.ex` is executed only once and it should not really matter whether the `ExUnit` is already started or not.

Comment: @mudasobwa I think that as soon as `ExUnit` start it will try to run all tests, so I assume that this is important to put it strictly before.

Comment: @Hauleth mudasobwa is right. The documentation of `ExUnit.start` says: "Starts ExUnit and automatically runs tests right before the VM terminates." I've also tested this by adding code after `ExUnit.start()` and it executes before the tests are run. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: My bad. But that is nice idea, surprising one, but nice.

Comment: Now I think that I was _wrong_. There could be a race condition between a tests running and the rest of `test_helper.exs` processing, since it’s _not_ compiled, but _intepreted_ (`exs` is a script.)

Comment: @mudasobwa but the tests are run just before the VM terminates. Try adding `Process.sleep(10000)` after `ExUnit.start` and the tests won't start executing for 10 seconds.

Comment: @Dogbert ah, indeed, I missed _“just before the VM terminates”_ part.

Comment: I don't think this will allow DB setup though, because the DB connection hasn't started yet